# Can I use Github desktop with a manual Git project? (Commercial)

Tags: git, github

I have been using Git to track changes in a new software project at work. Now Git is free and open source so I can use it in a commercial environment. However, I've started using Github Desktop to make it a bit easier to comment on commits.

Question is; am I allowed to use Github Desktop without paying Github for one of their organization or enterprise licenses?
The .git folder is on one of our servers and I am the sole user who manages it manually. A colleague is under the impression I need to pay to use their Desktop client - but my argument is, it's free, and you pay Github for private repositories and hosting packages. Although I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can(free). If your usage is just to commit on any open sourced projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Github Desktop personal completely free, but because your project is commerial you properly do not want to share your code online.

As long as you do **not** press the Sync button your code stays locally stored.

[image: github]